# Trying to get matrix build with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

The gSize comes from user (4/6/8)

I would like to make it a matrix, but I'm getting an array of 16 rows - why?

my code is

```js
function createBoard(gSize) {

  var board = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gSize; i++) {
    // board.push([])
    for (var j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
      // board[i][j] = empty
      board.push({
        posi: i,
        posj: j,
        minesAroundCount: 4,
        isShown: true,
        isMine: false,
        isMarked: true,
      })
    }
  }

  return board
}

console.log(
  createBoard(4)
);
```

Comment: you're pushing to board gSize * gSize elements - what is it you wanted to do?

Comment: Please provide output and EXPECTED output. "What is wrong" is not enough. If you click `<>` you can create a [mcve]

Comment: what makes you assume anything is wrong? (except for the unrelated Java tag you put up)

Comment: i would like to make it matrix, im getting array of 16 rows.

Comment: "my code is ... What is wrong?" - That's like "this is my car. what is wrong?" - we can't tell because you don't tell us what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: uncomment `// board.push([])` ... change `board.push({` to `board[i].push({`

Comment: missed clicked on the java tag :) sorry

Comment: I made your question answerable  - please pay attention next time. Have a read of [ask]

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks!

Comment: okey @mplungjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add inner arrays to get a matrix and then push to the inner arrays.

```
function createBoard(gSize) {
  var board = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gSize; i++) {
    board[i] = [];                    // create nested array
    for (var j = 0; j < gSize; j++) {
      board[i].push({                 // push to the inner array
        posi: i,
        posj: j,
        minesAroundCount: 4,
        isShown: true,
        isMine: false,
        isMarked: true,
      })
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

ES6 with spread for objects

```
function createBoard(length) {
    const defaults = { minesAroundCount: 4, isShown: true, isMine: false, isMarked: true };
    return Array.from(
        { length },
        (_, posi) => Array.from(
            { length },
            (_, posj) => ({ posi, posj, ...defaults })
        )
    );
}
```